# Compare TreeViews and remove extra items

Tags: vb6

Treeview1 has a-z zip names and each zip has child items.
Treeview2 has same zip names but each extra unwanted child items may exist. I need to remove the extra items from Treeview2.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that should work, with useful functions for later in your project:

```
Private Sub PruneTreeView(ByRef p_objSourceTreeView As TreeView, ByRef p_objTargetTreeView As TreeView)
    Dim objSourceNode As Node
    Dim objMatchNode As Node
    Dim objSourceChildNode As Node
    Dim objTargetChildNode As Node
    Dim fFound As Boolean
    Dim iNodeIndex As Integer
    Dim sSummary As String

    ' Build summary string
    sSummary = "Prune TreeView Summary:" & vbCrLf

    ' Get first node from Source TreeView
    Set objSourceNode = p_objSourceTreeView.Nodes(1)

    Do While Not objSourceNode Is Nothing

        ' Check if node has children, otherwise no need to look for match
        If objSourceNode.Children > 0 Then

            ' Find matching node in Target TreeView
            Set objMatchNode = GetMatchingNode(p_objTargetTreeView, p_objTargetTreeView.Nodes(1), objSourceNode)

            If Not objMatchNode Is Nothing Then

                sSummary = sSummary & "Source Node '" & objSourceNode.Text & "' Found in Target." & vbCrLf

                ' Check all children in Target Node
                If objMatchNode.Children > 0 Then

                    ' Set Found flag to False
                    fFound = False

                    ' Get first Child of Target
                    Set objTargetChildNode = objMatchNode.Child

                    Do While Not objTargetChildNode Is Nothing

                        ' Look for match in Source Tree
                        fFound = Not GetMatchingNode(p_objSourceTreeView, objSourceNode.Child, objTargetChildNode) Is Nothing

                        ' Keep Index reference
                        iNodeIndex = objTargetChildNode.Index
                        sSummary = sSummary & "Target Child Node '" & objMatchNode.Text & ":" & objTargetChildNode.Text & "'"

                        ' Go to next sibling
                        Set objTargetChildNode = GetNextSibling(p_objTargetTreeView, objTargetChildNode)

                        If fFound Then
                            sSummary = sSummary & " Found in Target." & vbCrLf
                        Else
                            ' No Match found
                            sSummary = sSummary & " Not Found in Target: Deleting at Index " & iNodeIndex & vbCrLf
                            p_objTargetTreeView.Nodes.Remove iNodeIndex
                        End If

                        DoEvents

                    Loop

                End If

            End If ' MatchNode exists

        End If ' Source Node Children > 0

        ' Go to next sibling
        Set objSourceNode = GetNextSibling(p_objSourceTreeView, objSourceNode)

    Loop

End Sub
```

The following are Helper functions I wrote to handle common tasks while looking up nodes:

```
Function GetMatchingNode(ByRef p_objTreeView As TreeView, ByRef p_objStartNode As Node, ByRef p_objCompareToNode As Node) As Node
    Dim objNode As Node

    ' Get First Node
    Set objNode = p_objStartNode

    ' Check all Siblings and match on Text property
    Do While Not objNode Is Nothing
        If objNode.Text = p_objCompareToNode.Text Then
            ' Match found
            Set GetMatchingNode = objNode
            Exit Do
        Else
            Set objNode = GetNextSibling(p_objTreeView, objNode)
        End If
    Loop

    Set GetMatchingNode = objNode

End Function

Function GetNextSibling(ByRef p_objTreeView As TreeView, ByRef p_objNode As Node) As Node
    If HasSibling(p_objTreeView, p_objNode) Then
        Set GetNextSibling = p_objTreeView.Nodes(GetNextSiblingIndex(p_objNode))
    Else
        Set GetNextSibling = Nothing
    End If
End Function

Function HasSibling(ByRef p_objTreeView As TreeView, ByRef p_objNode As Node) As Boolean
    HasSibling = Not (p_objNode.LastSibling Is p_objNode)
End Function

Function GetNextSiblingIndex(ByRef p_objNode As Node) As Integer
    With p_objNode
        GetNextSiblingIndex = .Index + .Children + 1
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: it removes all child items from 1941,zip and others? instead of removing items that did not match with listview1  PruneTreeView TreeView1, TreeView2

Comment: your image looks fine,let me re test it again. 3rd time.

Comment: i used Private Sub prune_Click()
PruneTreeView TreeView1, TreeView2
End Sub   ' and still it removes all child items on few or more parent nodes., your image looks fine and that is the way i want it to work just not sure why its removing all rather then un-matched only wiered.

Comment: Changes made, I had some important flaws in my logic, the current code should work properly. You can also use the `sSummary` variable to display the changes that were made.

Comment: From that video, in the 720.zip file on the right (1101-5t.047, 1102-5st.047, etc) , I didn't see any matches for what's in the 720.zip on the left (126047-1101.5t, 136047-1104.5n, ...) so it looks like it's working properly! It deleted everything in 720.zip on the right because nothing matches.

Comment: ahh let me double check agaiun

Comment: ok here you go https://streamable.com/h5c92 , i think you fixed it ,it was my problem not checking ,1 issue it freezes the ui can we add do events were it freezes,once again i sincerely apologies.

Comment: Yes, just add some extra DoEvents... I had one in the middle loop, I expected it to be enough but adding more is fine!

Comment: thank you so much. can i ask a question regarding another project?

Comment: Of course, please create a new question like you have been doing...

Answer (score 0):

all credits go to **Étienne Laneville**

```
 Private Sub PruneTreeView(ByRef p_objSourceTreeView As TreeView, ByRef p_objTargetTreeView As TreeView)
            Dim objSourceNode As Node
            Dim objMatchNode As Node
            Dim objSourceChildNode As Node
            Dim objTargetChildNode As Node
            Dim fFound As Boolean
            Dim iNodeIndex As Integer
            Dim sSummary As String

            ' Build summary string
            sSummary = "Prune TreeView Summary:" & vbCrLf

            ' Get first node from Source TreeView
            Set objSourceNode = p_objSourceTreeView.Nodes(1)

            Do While Not objSourceNode Is Nothing

                ' Check if node has children, otherwise no need to look for match
                If objSourceNode.Children > 0 Then

                    ' Find matching node in Target TreeView
                    Set objMatchNode = GetMatchingNode(p_objTargetTreeView, p_objTargetTreeView.Nodes(1), objSourceNode)

                    If Not objMatchNode Is Nothing Then

                        sSummary = sSummary & "Source Node '" & objSourceNode.Text & "' Found in Target." & vbCrLf

                        ' Check all children in Target Node
                        If objMatchNode.Children > 0 Then

                            ' Set Found flag to False
                            fFound = False

                            ' Get first Child of Target
                            Set objTargetChildNode = objMatchNode.Child

                            Do While Not objTargetChildNode Is Nothing

                                ' Look for match in Source Tree
                                fFound = Not GetMatchingNode(p_objSourceTreeView, objSourceNode.Child, objTargetChildNode) Is Nothing

                                ' Keep Index reference
                                iNodeIndex = objTargetChildNode.Index
                                sSummary = sSummary & "Target Child Node '" & objMatchNode.Text & ":" & objTargetChildNode.Text & "'"

                                ' Go to next sibling
                                Set objTargetChildNode = GetNextSibling(p_objTargetTreeView, objTargetChildNode)

                                If fFound Then
                                    sSummary = sSummary & " Found in Target." & vbCrLf
                                Else
                                    ' No Match found
                                    sSummary = sSummary & " Not Found in Target: Deleting at Index " & iNodeIndex & vbCrLf
                                    p_objTargetTreeView.Nodes.Remove iNodeIndex
                                End If

                                DoEvents

                            Loop

                        End If

                    End If ' MatchNode exists

                End If ' Source Node Children > 0

                ' Go to next sibling
                Set objSourceNode = GetNextSibling(p_objSourceTreeView, objSourceNode)
        DoEvents
            Loop

        End Sub
```